# Unable to connect to SQL server through Azure web app

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, azure

I'm remotely debugging a web app hosted on Azure to try and find out why I can't do anything related to database access. I find that I get this error when I try to write to the database (I haven't tested if it happens when I read):

`A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)`

My current Azure subscription is the free trial if that makes any difference. I don't know how I would enable remote connections for an Azure SQL server. I can connect to my server fine from my local machine as I have added its' IP to the server's firewall.

I'm sorry for the vague question but I have nowhere to go with this.

Comment: are you sure that you have the right credentials in sql server? attention that depending on the way you configured your azure DB you can either only connect directly to a specific database (that way you must specify your initial catalog when connecting) or to all server. Make sure that your ip is right on azure portal.

Comment: I have verified the connection string is correct in the web app

Comment: that error only occurs in the web app? you can connect to database via sql server?

Comment: Have you enabled access for Azure services? Beneath the ip configuration settings where you allowed the ip address for your local machine is a section Allowed Services: Windows Azure Services should be set to yes.

Comment: @DiogoCunha Yes I can connect in Management Studio perfectly fine.

Comment: @AlexS Yes I have enabled that.

Comment: your app is not connecting at all to Sql Server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have your connection string set up correctly?

Try the various options here: https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-azure/

try the user ID as: username@servername.database.windows.net

Comment: In my * - Web Deploy (where * is my project name) I have the following: `<Destination Path="Data Source=[redacted].database.windows.net;Initial Catalog=*_db;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=frayt;Password=[redacted]" />
          <Object Type="DbCodeFirst">
            <Source Path="DBMigration" DbContext="*.Model.DataContext, *.Model" MigrationConfiguration="*.Model.Migrations.Configuration, *.Model" Origin="Convention" />
          </Object>`

Comment: No difference. I'll submit the request, the website loads for about 60 seconds then I'll see the original exception.

Comment: I added a connection string in my Web.config file pointing to the Azure SQL server but I see when I do `update-database` for entity framework, the data source is still set at ./SQLExpress i.e. my local machine. I assumed that Visual Studio would set everything up when I published my website to Azure but seemingly not.

Comment: It's working! Really annoyed that Microsoft don't mention anywhere that you have to manually create the connection string in your Web.config

Answer (score 3):

There is an option with the SQL Server Network and Firewall that should be turned on in order to be able to access it from within Azure App Services.

[Allow Azure Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/network-access-controls-overview#allow-azure-services)

1. Go to Firewalls and virtual networks on your SQL Server
2. Turn 'Allow Azure services and resources to access this server' to 'Yes'
3. Save your changes
4. Now you should be able to access the SQL Server